# Get number of frames in scene from the command line?

Tags: command-line

I'd like to know if there is a command-line option (or combination, or a way!) to get the number of frames that are included in a specified blender scene; for example I'd like to use is like this:

```
$ blender <option> file.blend
$ Number of frames in blender scene: xxxx
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**, Blender has no command line arguments to return the number of frames in the scene, however you can use a script.

Here is a script as mentioned by CoDEmanX above:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
print("Scene %r frames: %d..%d = %d" % (scene.name, scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end, scene.frame_end - scene.frame_start + 1)) # frame_end is included
```

Store this as a .py file, then you can run it like so:

```
blender -b <path-to-blend-file> -P <path-to-script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll test it in a couple of hours and let you know if that is what I want!

Comment: Well, I tried it but I think it doesn't return the number of animation frames correctly. It always returns 1...250 frames; I tested with a couple of scenes but "dynamicpaint_waves.blend" scene from blender's own demo files has 340 animation frames and your script only returns 250.

Comment: @jtimz Try placing `-P <path-to-script>` behind `<path-to-blend-file>`, so the script is executed after the file is loaded.

Comment: Ah yes, it returns the startup.blend frames otherwise. Fixed.

Answer (score 10):

This information is stored in the `blend` files header, so you can find out without having to load Blender at all.

This has the advantage you can scan a directory of 100's (or 1000's) of blend files in a very short time (a few seconds even if the files are large).

Blender comes with a script in `scripts/modules/blend_render_info.py` which can extract this data from a blend file (you don't even need Blender to be installed just a copy of this file and Python is enough).

You can load the script as a module or execute it directly.

command line example:

```
# python blend_render_info.py /path/to/my_test.blend
1 250 Scene
```

python example:
*This can run inside blender,
otherwise `blend_render_info.py` will have to be in Python's `sys.path`*

```
import blend_render_info

filepath = "/path/to/my_test.blend"
frame_start, frame_end, scene = blend_render_info.read_blend_rend_chunk(filepath)

print("total frames:", (frame_end - frame_start) + 1)
```

As you can see the frame range and active scene is stored, if you want more info you'll have to use a script and load the file into Blender.

Answer (score 3):

The Command Line reference does not list a command to output the number frames of a scene:
https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line.html

But you can tell Blender what scene to use and to render all frames (if that is what you want):

```
 -a or --render-anim 
     Render frames from start to end (inclusive)

 -S or --scene 
     Set the active scene  for renderingame> for rendering
```

It probably uses the frame range as set within the .blend (Timeline).

Or is your definition of "all frames" from first **key**frame to last?
In that case, you need a little script that determines the range and returns the info. A python script can be run like this:

```
 -P or --python 
     Run the given Python script file
```

If you want to find the min and max keyframe of any object in a scene, you can use this:

```
import bpy

keyframed_ranges = {}

for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    lower = []
    upper = []
    for ob in scene.objects:
        if (ob.animation_data is not None and
            ob.animation_data.action is not None):

            # Note: frame_range.y is frame_range_x+1 if there's just a single keyframe!

            lower.append(ob.animation_data.action.frame_range.x)
            upper.append(ob.animation_data.action.frame_range.y)

    if not lower or not upper:
        keyframed_range = scene.frame_start, scene.frame_start
    else:
        keyframed_range = min(lower), max(upper)

    keyframed_ranges[scene.name] = keyframed_range

print(keyframed_ranges)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Well, what I want to do is to be able to determine the total frames that would be rendered (i.e. individual jpeg's) in order to split the work into multiple discrete tasks; but to do that and split my scene as evenly as possible I want to be able to know beforehand the length of the scene (total individual frames to be rendered) in order to calculate an accurate step. So I guess this would fall in the second category you mentioned.